# Unable to run the given code to read the file add new column and want to read the 5 rows in windows

Tags: python, data-analysis

```
import pandas as pd
sample_import=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/python programing/allpythonfiles/simple_csv.csv')

new_column_values=list(range(1,10))
sample_import['new_column'] = new_column_values[:len(sample_import)]

subset=sample_import.iloc[:5,:3]

print(subset[['col1','col2','col3','new column']])`
```

```
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3978, in _setitem_
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4172, in _set_item       
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4912, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 561, in require_length_match    
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (9) does not match length of index (29)
PS C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python programing>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 29 rows in your DataFrame, but you try to assign a list of 9 values to a new column. This causes a mismatch between the length of values and the length of index.

One way to fix this error is to use the pandas Series function to convert the list or numpy array into a pandas Series that matches the length of the DataFrame column. If the list or numpy array has less elements than the DataFrame rows, then NaN values will be filled in.

```
import pandas as pd
sample_import=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/python programing/allpythonfiles/simple_csv.csv')

new_column_values=list(range(1,10))
sample_import['new_column'] = pd.Series(new_column_values) # convert list to Series

subset=sample_import.iloc[:5,:3]

print(subset[['col1','col2','col3','new_column']])
```